# InvocationTargetException when trying to read powerpoint file attachment from lotus notes documents

Tags: java, apache-poi, lotus-notes

I have a lotus notes hava agent that retrieves slide data from powerpoint files attached in lotus notes documents with the help of Apache POI. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, and if it doesn't work, here's the common error stack trace.

Java Console:

```
Start
blahblahblah.pptx
File has pptx extension
Reading embedded object...
Read existing presentation
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow.<init>(XMLSlideShow.java:91)
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow.<init>(XMLSlideShow.java:96)
    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:98)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSLFFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:426)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155)
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow.<init>(XMLSlideShow.java:89)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSLFFactory.java:64)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.createElementXobj(Cur.java:257)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.startElement(Cur.java:2992)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxHandler.startElement(Locale.java:3198)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportStartTag(Piccolo.java:1082)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseAttributesNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1802)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseOpenTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1521)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1362)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.yylex(PiccoloLexer.java:4678)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yylex(Piccolo.java:1290)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yyparse(Piccolo.java:1400)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:714)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3439)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1270)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1257)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.SldDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide.<init>(XSLFSlide.java:67)
    ... 12 more
Next Document
Finished scanning reports
```

Code Snippet:

```
if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase("pptx")) { // If file is 2007+ powerpoint file
    System.out.println("File has pptx extension");
    try {
        System.out.println("Reading embedded object...");
        IS = att.getInputStream(); //EmbeddedObject att = (EmbeddedObject) rtnav.getElement();
        System.out.println("Read existing presentation");
        XMLSlideShow pptxshow = new XMLSlideShow(IS);
        System.out.println("Getting slides from file...");
```

As you can see, the error is thrown on the `XMLSlideShow pptxshow = new XMLSlideShow(IS)`

The attachment it read is only 1155 KB.

Comment: Key bit looks to be `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` - what happens if you bump up the JVM heap size to something decent?

Comment: Isn't that the default JVM hava heap space in lotus notes is 64 MB?

Comment: If it's that tiny, then that'll certainly be your issue! Try setting it to something sensible

Comment: Okay, so after setting JavaMaxHeapSpace = 512MB in notes.ini, it worked! Thanks and also please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: FYI: Setting JavaMaxHeapSize that large on a Domino server can have nasty side effects. Your file is only 1 MB, so it's very hard to believe that you need 512 MB of heap to deal with it. Strongly suggest you try 128 MB. Also strongly suggest that you search your code for memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

The key bit in your exception is

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

This seems to be being caused by you using the default JVM heap size, and a very small default at that

Just bump up the maximum java heap size, and you should then be fine!